# How to access Objective C unnamed parameters of some method?

Tags: objective-c, methods, syntax, parameters

All I've found on the web about parameters of methods in Objective C is that they are optional, but if I don't label each input parameter of some method, how do I access them?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
 - (float) divNum1: (int) AndNum2: (int);
```

then it doesn't even compile, saying that

> an identifier was expected before ;

So on the implementation of the method above I want to access each of the input parameters:

```
- (float) divNum1: (int) AndNum2: (int)
{
    return <first parameter> / <second parameter>;
}
```

I know how to solve this using labels, what I need is the solution for this problem without naming each parameter.

Comment: So is the problem that you don't understand the syntax of Objective-C method declaration?

Comment: The part that is optional is not the part you seem to think is optional.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, now I see my mistake. What is optional is the additional parts of methods names, not the parameters names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The labels are the things *before* the type. You can omit them (except for the first one, because it is the name of the method). So you are allowed to declare this:

```
- (float) divNum1: (int) a : (int) b;
```

And define it like this:

```
- (float) divNum1: (int) a : (int) b {
    return (float)a /(float)b;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
[self divNum1:5 :6];
```

You cannot omit the names *after* the types because those are the internal names, used by the body of the method.

Answer (score 2):

You were mistaken in which part of the method is optional. The pseudo argument method name is optional, but all physical parameters must be there. Take the following method in to consideration.

```
- (void)parameterOne:(int)p1 :(int)p2
//                          ^^^
{
    int p3 = p1 * p2;
}
```

This method would be called like so.

```
[self parameterOne:10 :20];
```

So as you can see, the corresponding section of the method *name* is optional, but not the argument names.

Answer (score 0):

The interleaved argument name is optional, not the parameter names.

Anyways, here's the **declaration**:

```
- (float)div:(int)num1:(int)num2;
```

The **usage**:

```
[self div:2 :3];
```

The **implementation**:

```
- (float)div:(int)num1:(int)num2 {
    return (float)num1 / num2;
}
```

The method itself is called `-div::`. (Note the two colons)

But Apple [discourages this behaviour](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001751-BCIJHEDH).

If you do not like this, you can try something like swift where you can omit many parts of a method.

You should be using `- (float) div:(int)num1 with:(int)num2;` instead.

Comment: And to be clear, the name of the method is `div::` (note the two colons - they are part of the method name).